# Removing all the eventSources in fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar

I have two types of events in my fullCalendar. Few are the fetched from the eventSources using :

```
    $('calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource' , 'source')
```

And few are created by the user. I am using

```
    $('calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true)
```

Now upon clicking a button I want to remove all the events that are obtained from the eventSources and retain those that are created by the user.

I tried doing :

```
     $('calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource' , function(e){ return true ; } ) ;
```

But that doesn't work. How do I achieve doing the job ?

Comment: You can do it in two ways. Hold a reference to the sources passed in the `addEventSource`. This reference can be used to remove them with the `removeEventSource` function. Or you can add a property to all the events created by the user and call `.fullCalendar( 'removeEvents', function(e){ return !e.customProperty })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did exactly what you want to do in a recent project.
Fullcalendar supports nonstandard fields.

> **Non-standard Fields**
>
> In addition to the fields above, you may also include your own
> non-standard fields in each Event Object. FullCalendar will not modify
> or delete these fields. For example, developers often include a
> description field for use in callbacks such as eventRender.
>
> [Source](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)

So you could do something like

```
//Save user created event
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
    title: title,
    end: end,
    start: start,               
    editable : true,
    //nonstandard field
    isUserCreated: true,
    description: description,               
});
```

then to remove events that hasn't been created by user

```
//Get all client events
var allEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');

var userEventIds= [];

//Find ever non usercreated event and push the id to an array
$.each(allEvents,function(index, value){
    if(value.isUserCreated !== true){
    userEventIds.push(value._id);
    }
});

//Remove events with ids of non usercreated events
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents', userEventIds);
```

or if you need less control then simply (as @A1rPun suggested)

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents', function(e){ return !e.isUserCreated});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply call:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSources');
```

Comment: this answer is amazing !! very simple. Other solution is very complex. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

They added ways to remove both event sources and events in event calendar, as long as you're using 2.8.0.

To remove all event sources or all events from full calendar, do the following:

`$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSources', optionalSourcesArray)`

If optionalSourcesArray isn't defined, it simply removes all event sources. In my case, I needed to remove event sources, so I called:

`$('#calendar').fullCalendar( ‘removeEvents’, idOrFilter )`

See the documentation for both method calls here:

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/removeEventSources
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/removeEvents

You can read more about the original removeEventSources pull request and how it's actually implemented here:

https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/948